# All threads when running a java project

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, visualvm

I am using visualVM to monitor my java program, started within eclipse.
I am using quartz scheduler and have 2 worker threads, so there are 3 threads for quartz.
I have another thread running listening to a socket.
Then I have a thread pool with 50 threads.

But it shows there are total 164 live threads with 110 are deamon threads.
I saw there are dataStreamer. Does java have a thread to handler data stream?

I also saw there are many PesponseProcessor for block blk_... 
What does those threads response for, and witch kind of block it point to?

Comment: Click on a thread or grab a thread dump. Chances are that by analysing stack dumps you will discover which frameworks/libraries use them.

Answer (score 0):

Please note VisualVM will launch 5 threads of his own for the RMI communication and serialization of thread dumps. You can completely ignore those.